# What effect do R5,R6,R7,R8 have on the following DSBSC Modulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, communication, modulation, active-filter

[image]

1. I know that the first 741 essentially adds m(t) and c(t).The gain should be 1 so why do we have 3.9kohms resistance ? What use is it ?
2. The second 741 circuit is a band pass filter . I think there is a high pass filter first (R7 and C1 ) and then a low pass filter (C2 and R9) and an amplifier at last. What use are R6 and R8 ? How do they contribute to gain ?

Comment: If I were to tell you that e.g. which resistors reduce the gain (compared to a short) and which increase it, would that be the answer you want?

Comment: Get a free sim tool and simulate it and find out.

Comment: Reconsider your first statement: "The first 741 essentially adds m(t) and c(t)."  Does it add?  Look how D1 and D2 are connected in the feedback loop.

Comment: Modulation != addition.

Comment: @JRE Thank You ! I read more about my problem and figured out many things like bandwidth and center frequency of the band pass filter. The output of switching modulator is 2m(t)c(t) and I learned about it too. Should I answer my question or edit the question and update it ?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I figured most stuff except the use of 3.9k ohms in the filter. Could you tell me about that ?

Comment: @Andyaka Thank You ! Though, I was actually interested in the Math of it not the numbers .

Comment: If you figured it out, go ahead an make an answer of it.